# Angular app running auth via adal.js won't load template partials unless user logged in

Tags: angularjs, adal

I'm using [adal-angular.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) as part of my auth chain.

Everything works for pages that require auth. Pages that do *not* require auth will load, but they won't load any partials that are included in the view.

For example, the `index.html` page has this:

```
<ng-include src="'/module/utility/view/footer.html'"></ng-include>
```

The footer only appears if the user is logged in.

I suspect my problem is similar to [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/326) bug report, but I'm not quite getting there.

I tried adding `anonymousEndpoints` to my adal init, like so:

```
adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
    {
        tenant: "xxx", // Optional by default, it sends common
        clientId: "xxx", // Required
        anonymousEndpoints: ['/app/module/utility/view/footer.html']
        // also tried:
        //anonymousEndpoints: ['/app/module/utility/view/']
        //anonymousEndpoints: ['/']
        //and soforth.
    },
    $httpProvider
);
```

Still no footer. Also, no errors.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the answer was pretty simple.

What little documentation there is on this problem suggests this:

```
anonymousEndpoints: ['/app/module/utility/view/']
```

That didn't work for me. This did:

```
anonymousEndpoints: ['/module/utility/view/footer.html']
```

The path needs to be *relative to app.js*, which for me is in the app folder.

Comment: It is not relative to app.js. The library does a substring matching internally. So, if the url has a substring that matches any of the values in the anonymousEndpoints array, the url will be considered anonymous. Think of anonymousEndpoints as array of keywords. In your case,  url is `/module/utility/view/footer.html` and as `/app/module/utility/view` is not a valid substring, it does not match. this is the line of code that does the matching: `endpoint.indexOf(this.config.anonymousEndpoints[i]) > -1)`